# How to generate uniformly distributed sequences of random numbers?

Tags: random, bigint

I need to generate uniformly distributed binary sequences (strings) of length 1024? So that if I make an integer of such string it would be uniformly distributed. I could have generated random integer, but the range, I suppose is too wide [0 to 2^(2^10)]. What would you suggest?

Comment: If it's uniformly distributed, it's not random. What you could do, however, is split your range into X parts, get random numbers within those parts, combine results, and shuffle your results.

Comment: You could also just generate each random digit individually and loop until you get the length you need...

Comment: I thought random and uniformly distributed means the same... Ok, if I make a sequence of random binary digits, will it be also a random number or somehow (uniformly? normally?) distributed?

Comment: @Populus, I did just that, but it turns out that numbers from the middle of the range are way more likely to occur than those from borders.

Comment: @Populus Nonsense. Uniform distribution just means that each value in the range is equally likely to occur (when talking about a discrete, finite number of elements, which we are).

СашкоЛихенко How have you checked this? It's quite possible you're checking for the wrong thing.

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко which method did you try? Another way is to generate a random number in a higher base (e.g. 10) that you then convert back to binary, it would probably be quicker.

Comment: Used bit by bit random generation method. I (probably) shouldn't generate random ints of length of somewhat 309 digits...